# may or can in generally true sentences?

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider this definition of "**may**", given in https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/may

**Definition 3**: You use **may** to indicate that something is sometimes true or is true in some circumstances.

// *A vegetarian diet **may** not provide enough calories for a child's normal growth*.

Now consider this sentence, please:

*a) A vacant lot **can** produce an extraordinary variety of flora and fauna*. (~ A vacant lot **sometimes** produces an extraordinary variety of flora and fauna, i.e. it is **sometimes true**)

But, according to **definition 3** above, "may" should be able to replace "can" in sentence a). So we get the following sentence:

*b) A vacant lot **may** produce an extraordinary variety of flora and fauna.*

My question is: Do native speakers use *sentence b)* in the **same sense** of *sentence a)* (or definition 3)? like this:

*A vacant lot **may** produce an extraordinary variety of flora and fauna = A vacant lot **sometimes** produces an extraordinary variety of flora and fauna*.

Comment: Yes, both mean the same thing.

Comment: More strictly, (a) is not even true (a paved-over vacant lot cannot produce anything) - 'can' denotes ability and 'may' denotes permission.  'Might' is preferable for denoting possibility.